# how to write 8 bit using outStream.write(msgBuffer);

Tags: android

outStream.write(msgBuffer); 
It writes only first bit. how to write 8 bit out of it.If we are sending 00000001 means it writes only 0. But we want to write whole 8 bit how to achieve it.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ToggleButton power, simulation, reset, pause, replay, diagnose,
            abs, emergency;

```
private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;

// SPP UUID service
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
private static String address = "00:12:02:28:75:34";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    power = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    simulation = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.simulation_tb);
    reset = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.reset_bt);
    pause = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.pause_bt);
    replay = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.replay_bt);
    diagnose = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.diagnose_bt);
    abs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.abs_bt);
    emergency = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.emergency_bt);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();

    power.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (power.isChecked()) {
                String str = "1";
                int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
                String binarystr = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

                char[] buffer = new char[binarystr.length()];
                binarystr.getChars(0, binarystr.length(), buffer, 0);

                System.out.println("char array:: "
                        + Arrays.toString(buffer));

                byte[] binaryFormat = getbyteFromString(buffer);

                for (byte b : binaryFormat) {

                    sendData(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256)
                            .substring(1));
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LED ON",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                sendData("0");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LED OFF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });     
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.const_closeApp))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.const_yes),
                    dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.const_no),
                    dialogClickListener).show();

}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(new
            // BTStateChangedBroadcastReceiver());
            System.exit(0);
            finish();
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            // No button clicked
            break;
        }
    }
};

private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned
    // on
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if (btAdapter == null) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
        } else {
            // Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device)
        throws IOException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod(
                    "createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord",
                    new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection", e);
        }
    }
    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);

        Log.d(TAG, "...This is the value byte: " + msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: "
                + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg
                    + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
        msg = msg + ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString()
                + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static byte[] getbyteFromString(char[] binarystr) {
    int length = binarystr.length / 8;

    if (binarystr.length % 8 > 0)
        length++;

    int iterationCount = length;

    byte[] binaryFormat = new byte[iterationCount];
    int iter = iterationCount - 1;

    for (int i = binarystr.length - 1; i >= 0;) {

        byte byt = 0x0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

            if (i < 0)
                break;

            int b = binarystr[i] - 48;
            byt = (byte) (byt + (b << j));
            i--;
        }

        binaryFormat[iter] = byt;

        iter--;
    }

    return binaryFormat;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    // A MAC address, which we got above.
    // A Service ID or UUID. In this case we are using the
    // UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: "
                + e1.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    /*
     * try { btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID); }
     * catch (IOException e) { errorExit("Fatal Error",
     * "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + "."); }
     */

    // Discovery is resource intensive. Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection. This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error",
                    "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure"
                            + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit(
                "Fatal Error",
                "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:"
                        + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit(
                    "Fatal Error",
                    "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: "
                            + e.getMessage() + ".");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket."
                + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is not complete. Anyway, I suggest to use the [DataInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html) / [DataOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) of Android. Just wrap your streams into them. They provide methods for writing any kind of primitive datatype up to String with arbitrary encoding. All you need to do is use the writeString(...) method and use the read String method on the other side. This way you don't need to convert the String in order to write it into you stream and you don't need to care about how to reconstruct it from the stream.
If you only want to write Strings you can use the [BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) which allows you to only write Strings to an stream, you can use it like this to stick it onto a 'OutputStream'

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);
```

Comment: I added full code. In my arduino LCD it is just displaying '0' first bit. So can you tell me what I need to do to show in LCD 00000001 when I click on and 00000000 when I click off in android device.

Comment: Use the DataOutputStream on the Android side and you'll have no problems there. Can you also post the part of your Arduino code which handles the communication? Maybe there is also something wrong.

Comment: No I am not using any Arduino code for communication, I am using first time this Arduino. I found the code for LED ON and LED OFF I used the same code, In Arduino LCD when I click ON it was displaying 1 and when I press OFF it was displaying 0. But requirement is it should display 00000000 8-bit when I press off and when I press ON it should display 00000001.